# Ошибка отправки фото из админки

Tags: php, laravel

при отправке формы из админки, для публикации постов, мне выдает ошибку в консоли

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
app.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at t.value (app.js:1)
    at o.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at o.t._render (app.js:1)
    at o.r (app.js:1)
    at fn.get (app.js:1)
    at fn.run (app.js:1)
    at ln (app.js:1)
    at Array.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at Gt (app.js:1)
Vt @ app.js:1
app.js:1 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at t.value (app.js:1)
    at keydown (app.js:1)
    at qt (app.js:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.n (app.js:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.Xr.i._wrapper (app.js:1)
Vt @ app.js:1
app.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at t.value (app.js:1)
    at o.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at o.t._render (app.js:1)
    at o.r (app.js:1)
    at fn.get (app.js:1)
    at fn.run (app.js:1)
    at ln (app.js:1)
    at Array.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at Gt (app.js:1)
Vt @ app.js:1
6api/blog:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
ui.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app.js:1 POST https://www.monolit-zabor.ru/api/blog 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
(anonymous) @ app.js:1
t.exports @ app.js:1
t.exports @ app.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c.request @ app.js:1
r.forEach.c.<computed> @ app.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.js:1
saveProduct @ app.js:1
click @ app.js:1
qt @ app.js:1
n @ app.js:1
Xr.i._wrapper @ app.js:1
```

Думал ошибка в JS скриптах, но потом убедился, что это не так, открыл файл лога ошибок и обнаружил такую ошибку

[2020-10-28 10:24:11] local.ERROR: Can't write image data to path (/home/setbit/web/zabor/public/images/thumb/test.jpg) {"userId":1,"email":"admin@com.ru","exception":"[object] (Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException(code: 0): Can't write image data to path (/home/setbit/web/zabor/public/images/thumb/test.jpg) at /home/setbit/web/zabor/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php:143)
[stacktrace]

Я так понимаю ему не нравится путь до файла, или мой контроллер страницы, или конетроллер отправки картинок. Проверил права доступа к папке, стоят полные.
Вот собственно метод отправки картинки.

```
 protected $path = '/public/images';

        public function makeImage($image, $slug = null)
        {
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $imageThumbsPath = base_path().$this->path.'/thumb/';
            $imageFullPath = base_path().$this->path.'/full/';
            if(!file_exists($imageThumbsPath)) mkdir($imageThumbsPath,0750,true);
            if(!file_exists($imageFullPath)) mkdir($imageFullPath,0750,true);
            $imageName = $slug.'.'.$extension;
            $thumb = Image::make($image)
            ->fit(600, 450, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->upsize();
            });
            $thumb->save($imageThumbsPath.$imageName);
            $full = Image::make($image)
            ->fit(1280, 720, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->upsize();
            });
            $full->save($imageFullPath.$imageName);
            return $imageName;
        }
```

Метод сохранения для контроллера страницы

```
    public function store(Request $request, PageRequest $pageRequest)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('image')) $image = $this->image->makeImage($request->file('image'), $request->slug);
        elseif (!empty($request->image)) $image = $request->image;
        else $image = "";
        ($request->published == 'true' || $request->published == 1) ?
            $published = 1 :
            $published = 0;
        ($request->price == 'null' || $request->price == "") ? $price = "" : $price =  $request->price;

        $page = Page::create( $request->except([
                'image',
                'price',
                'published'
            ]) + [
                'image' => $image,
                'price' => $price,
                'published' => $published
            ]);
        return response()->json(['success'=>'ok','id'=>$page->id]);
    }
```

До этого сайт переезжал с локалки на хост, возможно где то не совпали пути для папок сохранения или какие то настройки?

Comment: Жалуется именно на сохранение картинки.

Comment: Извините за вопрос, все оказалось проще намного, нужно было сменить группу и владельца для всех папок сайта.